# Turn link background black on navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the inverse navbar in bootstrap when I add a dropdown menu and click on it the background color turns black and then turns back to the original color when I click off it.

I am trying to get me other links in the navbar to do the same. Here is one thing that I have tried for my home link:

```
.navbar .home > .active > a, 
.navbar .home > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar .home > .active > a:focus {

    background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

This doesn't seem to do anything though. Any ideas?

Comment: `.home` isn't a Bootstrap class. Can you post all of your code, or create a [bootply](http://bootply.com/new) to demonstrate?

Comment: Can you give an example in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this to your stylesheet overriding the existing `background-color` coming from bootstrap stylesheet for all the behaviors. You can remove the styling that you mentioned above

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Here the [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXPxOp)

Comment: On the demo it seems like Home just has a black background. How would you get it to change depending on which link was clicked?

Comment: which demo are you referring to... can you share with us the link ?